# Check Table Record Exist in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a script to check already exist in SQL Table

Something like this:

I have a table named as amx_amxadmins and want to check user `flag` is exist flag a show this but my script show all time i have flag

```
$username = $this->user->getUsername($this->session->userdata('userid'));
$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT `flags`, `username` FROM `".$amxadmins."` WHERE `flags`='a' AND `username`='".$username."' ");
 $row2 = $query2->row();
  if ($row2 != "a")
    {
      echo "If already flag a ";
    }else { 
      echo "If not "; 
    }
```

Comment: replace conditions as if ($row2->username != "a")

Comment: Same problem with errors Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: then first check what are you getting in $row2

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare entire object. Compare one field value as below

```
if ($row2->username != "a")
    {
      echo "If already flag a ";
    }else { 
      echo "If not "; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have fetched a row from db, So you need to check if row object empty  or not.

```
if ($query2->num_rows()>0)
{
  echo "If already flag a ";
}else { 
  echo "If not "; 
}
```

use above code in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I fixed my problem like this:

```
<?php
$username = $this->user->getUsername($this->session->userdata('userid'));
$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT `auth`, `flag_a` FROM `".$amxadmins."` WHERE `flag_a`='0' ORDER BY `auth`='".$username."' ");
if ($query2->num_rows() != 0)
{
  echo "If already flag a ";
}else { 
  echo "If not "; 
}       
?>
```